# Required field missing error in test case

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm writing a test case.  When I save I get the following error message:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Min_Rate__c, Max_Rate__c]: [Min_Rate__c, Max_Rate__c]
```

These are the two relevant lines of code:

```
Show__c s = new Show__c(Venue__c=a.id,Host__c=h.id,Active__c=true,Players_for_Max__c=100,Rate_Card__c=r.id,Min_Rate__c=110,Max_Rate__c=250);
insert s;
```

The error message corresponds to the `insert` line. Note that the fields that it claims are missing are parameters to the constructor. In fact, all of the fields in the constructor are required and none of the others are saying they are missing. There are no triggers that overwrite the "missing" fields either. The only thing I can think of is that the two fields are of type Currency and perhaps I'm not setting it correctly.

Comment: are you sure you have only one method/ one insert in your test class that is inserting the show__C object, have you checked if  there other test methods inserting the show__c object which might be missing the required fields?

Comment: The test class has only one method.

Comment: Would you have any trigger or workflow which would update this value?

Comment: Whats a.id? and h.id?

Comment: Will you like to paste the whole code for our debug ?

Answer (score 1):

There's [a lot that goes on with an insert](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).  I suggest using the debug log to see what the values are along the way. For example you can see what the exact values are when a workflow is firing.

Another possibility is that if you are developing in an IDE, the code on the server that is actually getting executed does not match what you are viewing in your IDE.  Double check that by viewing the actual class in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

The code you paste looks no problem to me. It can't be wrong with only the two lines. So the problem is caused by the other parts in your system.

I duplicate the comment by rao and Peter Knolie, the error can cause by the other classes that related to the controller and test class.

So, try to run the anonymous code in the **Developer console**, it would be the most quick way to identify the root-cause.

Answer (score 0):

Each org will make different fields required for each standard and custom object. If one of those objects is referenced in the object you're inserting in your test class, when you create the referenced object, it must also satisfy the requirements set for the org when it comes to required fields. Otherwise, any validation rules that fire when your test class is run, will cause your test class to fail.

As others have pointed out, very often the line number given where a test class fails is not the line number that's causing the problem, it's simply where the problem caught up with you. My recommendation is that you query all the objects you're creating in your test class to get the required fields for each of them.

A good example might be with Opportunity. Opportunity requires an Account. So any fields required by your org for a new Account must be included when you create the Account(s) used in your test class. You'll also need Contacts for an Opportunity. So any required fields for Contacts will also be required when you create them. The same would apply to the User that's going to be the Owner of the Opportunity. If you don't have all the required fields for the related objects, in addition to the required fields set by your org for Opportunity, your test class for a trigger, class, controller, etc that fires on Opportunity is destined to fail.

Comment: To the down voter: I have no problem with an answer being voted down if you disagree or believe it is incorrect. To help others understand why you voted it down, please leave a comment with your reason. Its much more helpful to the community when someone is given the opportunity to improve their answer or address any issues you may have with and answer so all may learn from your comments.

Comment: I've had this issue where I get the required field missing error on a specific field on a custom object. This field was deployed as a required field but was changes to not being required after a day. However, we're still getting this error once in a while on new records being inserted. I haven't been able to find out why this is happening. Please help if you have ideas as to what may be causing this. Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A, Odd that this would be random. Is there any conditional code or workflow that utilizes this field under particular conditions that don't often occur? If so, that's what I'd be looking for. I'm assuming you didn't make it required initially for good reasons. It's likely the field is needed someplace in the execution context of the 1st or subsequent triggers in the execution context (including workflow). Try a metadata search for the field reference.